# Mathematica looks blurred

Tags: display

I am trying out a trial version of Mathematica before actually purchasing it, the image looks blurred. Could someone please verify if this is normal. I do not remember seeing this in the v11.

[image: 0]

Comment: Are you on windows? They don't have high dpi support in the front end for windows yet, but 12.1 is right around the corner and I think will have high dpi support.

Comment: @user13892 Yes I am on Win 10 Pro.

Comment: @user13892 12.1 seems to be on Wolfram Mathematica Online. Wonder why the different version between online and desktop.

Comment: Desktop versions have a strict release cycle and are only released after complete quality assurance while cloud versions are in possession of Wolfram Research at all times so they are updated on the fly and apparently have a high tolerance since their bugs can be fixed without publishing any major releases. This is just my opinion of what happens.